# Naruto Shippuden - The 6th Hokage

Tags: naruto

After the fall of Konoha from the Pain attack, Tsunade was rendered inactive. As such, the elders 'crowned' Danzō as the new Hokage. However, shortly after the Five Kage Summit, he was killed by Sasuke and so was not a Hokage for long.

Given the fact that Danzō was only Hokage for a short amount of time, do we know if he is *really* classed as the 6th Hokage, or just a temporary replacement until Tsunade woke (like Kakashi after Danzō's death)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the anime at least,

> he never had time to go through the official ceremony before he was killed.  So no, he was only a candidate for Sixth Hokage, and never officially held the title.  You can see on his page at the Narutopedia that [Danzou was always referred to as "candidate".](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Danz%C5%8D_Shimura)